# Separating an html document by paragraphs

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

To my knowledge, there are many ways of formatting text into separate paragraphs in html. For example, one could have a `<br>` between two pieces of text. Or a `<p></p>` tag that breaks at the end. Or maybe even a `<pre></pre>` tag with newline characters somewhere.

My question is how do I account for all these different ways if I want to isolate each paragraph in any given webpage.

We need this functionality because we are creating a chrome extension that has to work on all websites. So we have to account for all ways that new paragraphs could happen.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by “paragraph” and what HTML constructs you will recognize as denoting or delimiting “paragraphs”.

Comment: That's precisely what we are trying to figure out. How can we, using javascript preferably, analyze a document to see where you can semantically separate everything into complete units of thought. The issue is that there are hundreds of ways to do this, and it becomes tough. Is there a way to go beyond the tags and see the deepest text representation of the document and only see the newline character or something like this?

Comment: that’s what makes it a design question, largely opinion-based, if not philosophical, and dependent on particular context and goals, hence off-topic for SO.

Comment: How could we approach it though? Maybe in the lower level dom there is a way that these tags all translate into a global newline character that we can look out for. It might be a design question but it still requires a lot of technicalities that we do not have. If we looked at it from a simple spacing perspective(anything that is in a different line is a new paragraph), is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Blessoul This would be a better criteria to put in a question. You should probably edit your question with that.